# how to handle expired access token in facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I found following code from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/), it is supposed to work and it has 2 errors.

First one is : `Trying to get property of non-object on line 38`, which starts from

```
if ($decoded_response->error)
```

Second error is `Trying to get property of non-object on line 54` which starts from

```
echo("success" . $decoded_response->name);
```

So following code is my full code that gets access token.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
<?php
  require_once('src/facebook.php');
  include_once('src/base_facebook.php');

  $app_id = "413030352142786";
  $app_secret = "518852750047ba579316a19d81c1e115"; 
  $my_url = "134061970136571";

  // known valid access token stored in a database 
  $access_token = "CAAF3ph9rwcIBAD5GrDLZBI6TFKlSb4jccEmIorCVjtfIeKIq7FjGKntMI5qnZCaNlXL8qy2g0gbjof3sRJYmgoDckG5ZBWpZBHjgZAn1e3sHTyxDdWwcCaZAiCylP5ayoWIMZBZCgNBL71I3myFYoDUYNZB4dH0xKJjAZD";

  @$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  // If we get a code, it means that we have re-authed the user 
  //and can get a valid access_token. 
  if (isset($code)) {
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
      . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
      . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
      . "&code=" . $code . "&display=popup";
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];
  }


  // Attempt to query the graph:
  $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?"
    . "access_token=" . $access_token;
  $response = curl_get_file_contents($graph_url);
  $decoded_response = json_decode($response);

  //Check for errors 
  if ($decoded_response->error) {
  // check to see if this is an oAuth error:
    if ($decoded_response->error->type== "OAuthException") {
      // Retrieving a valid access token. 
      $dialog_url= "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id 
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);
      echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url 
      . "'</script>");
    }
    else {
      echo "other error has happened";
    }
  } 
  else {
  // success
    echo("success" . $decoded_response->name);
    echo($access_token);
  }

  // note this wrapper function exists in order to circumvent PHP’s 
  //strict obeying of HTTP error codes.  In this case, Facebook 
  //returns error code 400 which PHP obeys and wipes out 
  //the response.
  function curl_get_file_contents($URL) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    $err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);
    if ($contents) return $contents;
    else return FALSE;
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your reply !!!

Comment: given that error, your json has probably failed to decode, return a `NULL` value, which you blindly tried to use as an object. Never assume an external resource succeeded. Always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply ! but where to return a null value?

Comment: you're not returning a null, json_decode probably is. do `var_dump($response)` and `var_dump($decoded_response)` and see what you get.